# How can I have a form submit 2 actions?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that I need to perform the following two actions upon submit:

```
<form action="MAILTO:name@email.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/xxxxx" method="POST">
```

Is there any way to get one form to process these 2 actions?

Comment: yep; it's called Ajax.

Comment: I'd shy away from `action="MAILTO:name@email.com"` though.

Comment: actually you don't even need ajax. Just use what you have now minus the first form tag and process the PHP via the `mail()` function or PHPmailer.